# setting html to position relative

Tags: html, css

I am curious how works position: relative in html tag. Can anyone explain? Is it positioned relative to document object or something like this?

```
   <footer class="footer">
     <div class="container">
       <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
     </div>
   </footer>

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to read a guide? It's always the best choice. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: [Here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a good tutorial to learn CSS Positioning

Comment: point 4 of this tutorial explained me what i wanted to know thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned).

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position: relative;` is positioned relative to its normal position.

Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually it won't make any sense if you use position relative with html tag.

```
position: relative;
```

positions the child with respect to its parent or to its neighboring elements.

You can try position: relative with body to position the body relative to the parent html.

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: Well its example from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ and without position: relative in html tag footer will not work properly. @Lal posted cool guide. I found answer in point 4. You can try it out and play a bit with different sizes of browser u will see the difference.